# How do i add a query string pair to an existing url in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am aware that I can access all external links on a page using something like:

```
// Get external links
$.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
        && (obj.hostname != location.hostname);
};
```

does anyone know how I can add a query string pair (along the lines of `?aid=1234567`)
to the URLs in the external links?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
// custom :external selector
$.expr[':'].external = function(obj){
    return !obj.href.match(/^mailto\:/)
            && (obj.hostname != location.hostname);
};

// put the new querystring pair on every external link
$("a:external").each(function() {
     $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "?aid=1234567");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  Didn't work at first until I put it in the $(document).ready() function, and now it works a treat.

Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, I guess I just made the assumption that you knew to put it there, but thank you for accepting.

Comment: my fault - should have said that I was new to jquery

Thanks again